# lua - late call of class destructor

Tags: c++, garbage-collection, lua, destructor

I am working on a c++ program which essentially just executes a lua script. In that lua script however classes are constructed, which have been exported from my c++ program to the lua script.

My main() c++ function just calls after some preparations...

```
    luabind::call_function<void>(m_L, "main");
```

Now my lua script looks like this

```
local function test()
local c = C()
end

function main()
    for i=1,2 do
        log(i)
        test()
    end
end
```

I have included a std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl; in C's destructor so I know when it is called. I would expect that lua's garbage collection calls the destructor of c everytime execution of test() ends, because that is when it falls out of scope. Instead I see the following output:

```
1
2
destructor
destructor
```

rather than

```
1
destructor
2
destructor
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I would expect that lua's garbage collection calls the destructor of c everytime execution of test() ends, because that is when it falls out of scope.

This is not the case. Lua's garbage collection does not run at the end of every scope. It is typical of garbage collected languages that you can't depend on when exactly the destructors are run, and in some languages an object may never be destroyed at all.

There is not any way to make Lua automatically destroy objects deterministically like C++ does.

If you have to depend on this then you may be able to get by with Lua's `collectgarbage` function, however it would probably be better to simply change your expectations and redesign accordingly.

[Here's](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.5) the Lua documentation on how their garbage collection works.

---

An example of using collectgarbage:

```
local function test()
    local c = C()
end

function main()
    for i=1,2 do
        log(i)
        test()
        collectgarbage "collect"
    end
end
```

Comment: hmm, that is rather unpleasant. now, I have reduced this example for clarity, but in my real application c is a huge object (some 100-1000 MB). that needs to be cleaned up! Is there any way to get my expected behaviour out of lua?

Comment: @chris.schuette: you could call the garbage collector manually if you really need to - `lua_gc` in C or `collectgarbage` in Lua

Comment: @chris.schuette: If you want a solution that's more fine-grained, you can have Lua call a function on the object that will delete it. Obviously, the Lua script will have to make sure not to touch it anymore afterwards.